# Database Transaction using Robotium

Tags: robotium

Heloo All,

I am automating the product developed using Robotium. Am able to cope with many of the modules. Only thing is I need to hardcode the validations like:

If userName is "xyz" then password has to be "12345". On hardcoding,the values as in-

solo.enterText(0,"xyz");
solo.enterText(1,"12345");

This works fine. But I just want to know if there is any way in which we can query the database being used, get the values from there and make the solo class validate the tests.

Any solution and Example for the problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to achieve this,

Step: 1. Read the values from database and store it in a XML.

```
    Class.forName(sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver).newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:odbc:myData, “”, “”);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query = “Select UserName, Password from Customers”;
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    StringBuffer xml = “<?xml version=‘1.0’?><myDatabase><customers>”;
    while (rs.next()) {
         xml.append(“<custRec><custUserName>”);
         xml.append(rs.getString(“UserName”));
         xml.append(“</custName><cusPassword>”);
         xml.append(rs.getInt(“Password”));
         xml.append(“</custPassword></custRec>”);
    }
    xml.append(“</customers></myDatabase>”);
```

Step: 2. Read the values from XML file and use it in the `Solo` class.

.

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(stringReader);    
DOMParser domParser = new DOMParser();
domParser.parse(inputSource);
Document document = domParser.getDocument();
NodeList userNameList = doc.getElementsByTagName(“custUserName”);
NodeList passwordList = doc.getElementsByTagName(“custPassword”);
```